# Filter array by string length in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm a really beginner in javascript

I have an array containing

```
array_1 = ["the","quick","brown","fox","jumped","over","the","lazy","dog"]
```

And I want another array but only with words that have length > 3

```
array_cleaned = ["quick","brown","jumped","lazy"]
```

How it is currently implemented:

```js
array_1 = ["the","quick","brown","fox","jumped","over","the","lazy","dog"]

array_clean = [];
for(var i=0; i<array_1.length; i++){
    if(array_1[i].length > 3) 
        array_clean.push(array_1[i]);
}

document.write(array_clean)
```

But I'm looking for a way to actually filter it. Any ideas?

Comment: Please define "doesn't seem to work", since [your code seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/d29b6zL3/).

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```js
const array_1 = ["the", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumped", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"];

const new_array = array_1.filter((element) => {
  return element.length > 3;
});

// OR refactor
// const new_array = array_1.filter( (element) => element.length > 3);

console.log(new_array)

// Output:
// ["quick", "brown", "jumped", "over", "lazy"]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can filter it

```
var array_cleaned = array_1.filter(function(x) {
    return x.length > 3;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the filter function, this works just fine I think.

```
arrayClean = [];
for(int i = 0; i<array1.length; i++) {
     if(array1[i].length < 3) {
          arrayClean[i] = array[i];
     }
}
```