# How to filter a string data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, servicenow

I have a string for example:-

```
String: Notification 'Arcosa-Incident assigned to my group' 8ff7afc6db05eb80bfc706e2ca96191f included recipients as manager of a group in the notification's "Groups" field: 'Ruchika Jain' 9efa38ba0ff1310031a1e388b1050e3f
```

So basically i convert it into an array using `.split(' ')` method to make it comma separated values, now i want to `filter` this array and want only values which are 32 character long and remove rest of values.

Please help me achieve this. Alternate solutions are also welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter array by string length in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28768952/filter-array-by-string-length-in-javascript) and [JScript: Take as input an array of strings, return new array containing only strings with fewer than five characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40177669)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to grab those IDs you can simply use a regex with `match` on the string without splitting/filtering it. (Note: I had to escape the single quotes in the text.)

```js
const str = 'String: Notification \'Arcosa-Incident assigned to my group\' 8ff7afc6db05eb80bfc706e2ca96191f included recipients as manager of a group in the notification\'s "Groups" field: \'Ruchika Jain\' 9efa38ba0ff1310031a1e388b1050e3f';

const matches = str.match(/[a-f0-9]{32}/g);
console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score -1):

Like so:

```
var arr = ...;
var filtered = arr.filter(word => word.length === 32);
```

Edit: this may be a bad idea if you want to parse only the GUIDs. It could certainly be that a name like "Ruchika" is also 32 characters long. Maybe, consider using regular expressions instead.

Comment: Can the downvoter please elaborate what's wrong with this answer?